# Android app doesn't save data in local sql database for permanent

Tags: android, sqlite, sdk

I'm having problems in saving data in phones local SQL database file. I'm using Cars.db file where I have two tables, car and favourites. When user selects to add car to favourites it adds the car to favourites but when I close the app and open it back again the app doesn't have any data in favourites table.

The code works to see list of cars in favourites and I can select any car from list to view details on the car as well. I have MyDBHandler class object initialized in main activity as static object and using that objects reference to insert, and query data from Cars.db file.

```
public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_Name = "Cars.db";
    private static final String TABLE_Cars = "Cars";
    private static final String Table_Favourite = "Favourite_Cars";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MyDbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        try {
            copyDataBase(context); //Copies databse file to phones data/data/... folder

            database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

private void copyDataBase(Context context) throws IOException {

    InputStream dbInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_Name);

    // Creates databases folder if it does not exist
    String destPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

    File destPathFile =  new File(destPath);
    if (!destPathFile.exists())
        destPathFile.mkdirs();

    String outFile = destPath + DB_Name;
    OutputStream dbOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = dbInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        dbOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    dbOutput.flush();
    dbOutput.close();
    dbInput.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Your old db is getting copied everytime you start the app. So your app session is over written everytime. Apply a if condition to check if db already exists. If no then only copy the db file to internal memory.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. Check the question's code again. I added the copyDatabase() function.

Comment: destPath should be this in order to avoid the overwrite the db file        String destPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"+DB_Name;

Comment: @nikhil.thakkar ohh, I see it now, I was checking if the directory exists if it doesn't then just create one but I was always copying the file. thanks, for pointing it out.